# Filtering a java list of duplicates and modifying

Tags: java

I have an arraylist:

```
List<MissingIdentifier> missing = new Arraylist<MissingIdentifier>();
```

The entity looks as follows:

```
    public class MissingIdentifier {    
    protected String Identifier;   
    protected Date from;    
    protected Date to;
}
```

When I convert the collection to a csv it comes out like so:

```
IDENTIFIER,FROM,TO
IDENTIFIER1,22/11/2017,22/11/2017
IDENTIFIER1,22/11/2017,22/11/2017
IDENTIFIER1,14/11/2017,14/11/2017
IDENTIFIER1,14/11/2017,14/11/2017
IDENTIFIER2,16/11/2017,16/11/2017
IDENTIFIER2,16/11/2017,16/11/2017
```

Is it possible to do something easily where it converts the arraylist so that it will give only one item for each identifier but include the min date as the 'from' and the max date as the 'to' for each identifier (getting rid of all duplicates):

```
    IDENTIFIER,FROM,TO
    IDENTIFIER1,14/11/2017,22/11/2017
    IDENTIFIER2,16/11/2017,16/11/2017
```

I would know how to do this with SQL easily, but I do not intend to persist this entity.

Comment: Is the equal method in your MissingIdentifier class already overridden?

Answer (score 2):

To prevent duplicates just override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods and then add your items to a `Set`.

I suggest you read about the [Set interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and the classes that implement it.

I just quickly generated `toString`, `equals` and `hashCode` methods in Eclipse that use all of the fields in your class:

```
public class MissingIdentifier {    
    protected String identifier;   
    protected Date from;    
    protected Date to;

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public Date getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(Date from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public Date getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(Date to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((from == null) ? 0 : from.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((identifier == null) ? 0 : identifier.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((to == null) ? 0 : to.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        MissingIdentifier other = (MissingIdentifier) obj;
        if (from == null) {
            if (other.from != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!from.equals(other.from))
            return false;
        if (identifier == null) {
            if (other.identifier != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!identifier.equals(other.identifier))
            return false;
        if (to == null) {
            if (other.to != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!to.equals(other.to))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MissingIdentifier [identifier=" + identifier + ", from=" + from + ", to=" + to + "]";
    }
}
```

Now I'm able to do this:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class DuplicateRemoveExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date now = new Date();

        MissingIdentifier id1 = new MissingIdentifier();
        id1.setTo(now);
        id1.setFrom(now);
        id1.setIdentifier("abc");

        MissingIdentifier id2 = new MissingIdentifier();
        id2.setTo(now);
        id2.setFrom(now);
        id2.setIdentifier("abc");

        Set<MissingIdentifier> mySet = new HashSet<>();
        mySet.add(id1);
        mySet.add(id2);

        System.out.println(mySet);
    }

}
```

and the output shows only a single item in the set:

`[MissingIdentifier [identifier=abc, from=Fri Nov 24 19:40:36 CST 2017, to=Fri Nov 24 19:40:36 CST 2017]]`

Lastly, you may notice I changed the name of your instance variable from `Identifier` to `identifier`. This is to conform with [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Please learn them and use them as it will help others to read your code more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest algorithm: Create an empty HashMap that has the key value based on your uniqueness need. Then loop over the input objects, and build up the map. Then you'll need to make another loop over the input array to generate max/min values that are complete for all data. You don't need to write any custom maps or override any equals methods or any of that. The other solutions posted are mostly making this hard when it's easy.

Answer (score -2):

you need to @override the equals and toString method 
And then you´ll be able to se for duplicates with a Collection :)

```
public class MissingIdentifier {    
   protected String Identifier;   
   protected Date from;    
   protected Date to;

   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
       return Identifier + from + to;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(MissingIdentifier other)
   {
      if (this.toString == other.toString) return true;
      return false;
   }
```

}

Comment: What is the compiler going to say about this: `@Override
   public boolean equals(MissingIdentifier other)`?

Comment: Also comparing `String` with `==` and you're not overriding `hashCode`